# In BF3, where are the game settings saved?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3, origin

This also applies to stuff like attachments chosen for each weapon, etc. (It takes a while to set them all, there are so many of them)

It seems like the game files are usually saved in an `Origin Games` folder but these settings seem to go with the Origin install: I have two different Origin installations loading the same set of game files, and they have different settings saved. How easy would it be to copy them over to a different installation of Origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post tells you how to back up your BF3 save files for transfer to another computer:
http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/battlefield-3-pc/1455727-solved-battlefield-3-orgin-backup-method.html
It should be in something like "C:\Games\Orgin Games" and then "Battlefield 3" or "BF3".
Additionally, you have the option of saving your games in the cloud through Origin.

Comment: Ah I forgot about the cloud feature. It's not enabled by default yet. I hope it saves control settings: I hate having to remap helicopter controls every time I set up the game.